# JavaFX Scene Builder Styling

Tags: javafx, styling, scenebuilder

Could someone give me some tips on how to style my JavaFx Application. I am using scene builder to put my app together. Would I have to import css files into my javafx project. An explanation on this would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways to do this, (from the `SceneBuilder`/inside the `FXML`) or the Java Code :

```
//Java Code :
root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
```

For the scenebuilder you use a relative path to the location of your `file.css` and assign to each graphical element (node) its (Id/StyleClass) in the properties section of the SceneBuilder.
The Id is marked by `#` sign example :

```
#styleID{
  -fx-background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this approach :)